# ggplot2 factor variable na

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a factor variable as a bar plot using `ggplot2`.

I create the variable like this:

```
survey$coffeeblack2[survey$coffee == 1] <- 2
survey$coffeeblack2[survey$coffee == 2] <- 1
survey$coffeeblack2[survey$coffee == 3] <- 1
survey$coffeeblack2[survey$coffee == 4] <- 1
survey$coffeeblack2[survey$coffee == 5] <- 0
survey$coffeeblack2[survey$coffee == 6] <- 1
survey$coffeeblack2[survey$coffee == "NA"] <- NA

survey$coffeeblack2 <- as.factor(survey$coffeeblack2)
summary(survey$coffeeblack2)
```

This summary command gives the following, correct, output:

```
0    1    2     NA's 
139  186  107    4
```

I use the following command to plot it:

```
ggplot(survey, aes(coffeeblack2)) + 
  geom_bar( aes(fill=..count..)) + 
  scale_fill_gradient("Count", low="green", high ="red") + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("0" = "Non-Drinker", "1" = "Adder", "2" = "Black", "NA" = "NA"))
```

It gives the following output:

[image]

The NA's plotted but are labelled "Non-Drinker." I figured out how to remove them from the graph, but how do I get them correctly labelled as NA?

(I also removed the

```
, "NA" = "NA"
```

and got the same result)

---

Updated with minimal working example:

```
library(ggplot2)
a <- c(1,2,2,3,3,3,NA,NA)
a.f <- as.factor(a)
summary(a.f)  

ggplot(as.data.frame(a.f), aes(a.f)) + geom_bar( aes(fill=..count..)) +  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("1" = "One", "2" = "Two", "3" = "Three", "NA" = "NA"))
```

[Example two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSQJm.png)

The example shows it says "One" when plotting the NAs

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about how to give a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: You can't `use x == 'NA'` to find missing values.  You'll need `is.na(x)` to identify the missing values.

Answer (score 0):

Set the factor labels **outside** of ggplot:

```
survey$coffeeblack2 <- as.factor(survey$coffeeblack2
    levels=c(0,1 ,2 ), # the values found in the first argument
    labels=c("Non-Drinker",  "Adder",  "Black")) # the labels to apply to those values
```

and let ggplot use the labels that are present in your data:

```
ggplot(survey, aes(coffeeblack2)) + 
  geom_bar( aes(fill=..count..)) + 
  scale_fill_gradient("Count", low="green", high ="red")
```

this is one of the specific purposes of the grammar of graphics -- to separate data manipulations (matching labels to values) from the mapping of data features to plot features, (i.e. data labels to axis labels).

Answer (score 0):

```
#some data
DF <- iris
DF[8:10, "Species"] <- NA
DF$Species <- as.character(as.integer(DF$Species))
```

Set `breaks` and `labels` like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
summary(DF$Species)
ggplot(DF, aes(x = Species)) + 
  geom_bar( aes(fill=..count..)) + 
  scale_fill_gradient("Count", low="green", high ="red") + 
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c("1", "2", "3", NA),
                   labels = c("Non-Drinker", "Adder", "Black", "NA"))
```

[image: resulting plot]